# regular expression for changing all IDs in a VCF file

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression

I have to change all the IDs (N=2734) in a VCF file. They look like these examples:

```
TEUBPD10006_TEUBPD10006 
TEUBPD10007_TEUBPD10007
TEUBPD10008_TEUBPD10008 
.
.
.
```

So, every single ID has to be changed to only contains the first part namely:  `TEUBPD10006`, `TEUBPD10007`, `TEUBPD10008` and so on.

In this case, how could I use Linux regular expression to get it done by only one attempt?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you think using a regular expression is the solution but if that isn't a strict requirement you can easily accomplish this with `awk`:

```
awk -F'_' '{print $1}' /path/to/file
```

Using gawk you can overwrite the file in place:

```
gawk  -i inplace -F'_' '{print $1}' /path/to/file
```

Or otherwise with a temporary file:

```
awk -F'_' '{print $1}' /path/to/file > /path/to/temp_file && mv /path/to/temp_file /path/to/file
```

If you *really* want to you can add a regular expression:

```
awk -F'_' '/.*/{print $1}' /path/to/file
```

There is no point in doing this though.

---

Alternatively you can use `sed` in combination with a regex:

```
sed -e 's/\(.*\)_.*/\1/g' /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 1):

Also this could help:

```
cut -f1 -d'_' file
```